Trouble loading an application in the iOS simulator
For years we have been signing our application and sending it to our content teams for use using our enterprise license.  As of late, (iOS 18 and Xcode 16.1) this has stopped working.  When they drag the app into the simulator it loads, but upon starting the app it crashes straight off, no crash logs to be found.
This feels like a security issue but can't seem to track it down.  Looking for suggestions or solutions.
Thanks in advance!

Distribution is intended for running an app on a device, not the simulator. This difference is made sharper, perhaps, because there is now a distinction between archiving for devices and archiving for the simulator. So if your goal is to have people run the app on the simulator, perhaps you would need to archive for the simulator explicitly.

Agree, but there is no real archive for simulator present.  My archive was targeted to a sim, and I have validated that the arch is arm64, but same issue.  I can drag it to the sim but it crashes super fast.

If you look in the scheme under Archive you will see a new checkbox, "Allow Archiving For Simulator". My point is that if you have not enabled that checkbox, you are archiving for a device, so your archive won't run on the simulator.
